# Having trouble assigning a matrix linked list to a variable (java)

Tags: java, matrix

So I'm having trouble assigning a linkedlist matrix to a variable :

Right now I have node methods prepared, one for the headers, and one for the entries :

```
public Node(double value, int row, int col)
{
    this.value = value;
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
}
public Node(Node rowLink, Node colLink, double value, int row, int col)
{
    this(value, row, col);
    this.rowLink = rowLink;
    this.colLink = colLink;
}
```

And I'm playing around, trying to figure out how to place these nodes into a linkedlist matrix, and assigning that linkedlist to a single variable, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so :

```
public SparseMatrix(Node[] r, Node[] c) {
    rowHeads = r;
    colHeads = c;

    Node rowHeads = r[0];
    Node colHeads = c[0];
    Node one = new Node(r[0],c[0],2,2,2);
}
//parameter n --> given matrix size n
public static SparseMatrix[] initializeByFormula(int n) {

Node[] c = new Node[n];
Node[] r = new Node[n];  

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     r[i]=new Node(0,i+1,0);
     c[i]=new Node(0,0,i+1);
}
    SparseMatrix[] B = new SparseMatrix[5];
    SparseMatrix ch = new SparseMatrix(r,c);
    B[0] = ch;
    //System.out.println(B[0]);
    SparseMatrix[] result = null;
    return result;
}
```

Whenever I try to print out the matrix (ch in this example), I get something like "matrixcomputation.SparseMatrix@2a139a55"

Can anyone hint me towards what I'm doing wrong? All help is appreciated?

Comment: Implement `toString()` method in `SparseMatrix` class.

Comment: You probably want to implement `toString()` in both `SparseMatrix` and in `Node`, because printing a `SparseMatrix` object is going to involve printing some `Node` objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "whatever you want to print when you place b[0] in System.out.println()";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every class in java has `toString()` method in it by default, which is
>   called by `System.out.println()` if you pass some object of a class to
>   it. When you try to print object of a class, the `System.out.println()`
>   method will call `toString()` of the class which returns the
>   `className@hashcode` of that object.

Hence you should implement your own `toString()` method for all the object you want to have a nice printing.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Node (value: " + this.value + " row: " + this.col + " row: " + this.col + ")";
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you implement the `toString()` for all the objects of you project you can have a behaviour where a container class prints out all the objects contained.

To be more concrete, in your example the `SparseMatrix` object could implement the `toString()` method and iteratively invoke for all the contained object the toString() method.

In this case a common best practice is the use of `StringBuilder` object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SparseMatrix(\n");
    for (Node n: this.nodes) {
       sb.append(n);
       sb.append("\n"); // or another delimiter you like
    }
    sb.append(")");    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually given something very similar in the node class that was given to us. But doesn't this only print out a single node? How would I use this to print out an entire matrix after I've linked all the nodes by column and row?

Comment: Hi @jameslin I've updated my answer adding a suggestion that explain what to do with a SparseMatrix

Comment: thanks so much for that. We were given a node class with a given toString method, and were told we are not to touch this class, so for some reason the toString method always calls that one, rather than my newly created overridden one. Do you have any idea why this might be?